# When to use temporary and saved registers in MIPS Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, mips

In this question:

x = x + y - 10 - A[20]

```
x - $s0
y - $s1
A - $s3
```

For my answer, I wrote:

```
add   $t0,   $s0,   $s1    # value of x ($s0) + y ($s1) gets stored in temp $t0
addi  $t0,   $t0,  - 10    # subtracts value of $t0 from 10. $t0 now holds the new value
lw    $t1,   80($s3)       # loads value of A[20] into new temp $t1
sub   $s0,   $t0,  $t1     # subtracts values $t0 from $t1 and stores it in x 
                           ($s0)
```

However the model solution says:

```
add   $s0,   $s0,   $s1   
addi  $s0,   $s0,  - 10    
lw    $t0,   80($s3)   
sub   $s0,   $s0,  $t0
```

Is my original answer correct? Doesn't it output the same result? If I am wrong, please explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both answers are correct; there are *many* ways to compile that expression, using whatever registers you want and also different orders of operations or different instruction choices.

There's no downside to writing a result to a register that an instruction reads as an input.  If there was more surrounding code as part of a large function, using fewer registers for temporaries could be an advantage.  The model solution is arguably more optimal than yours, repeatedly modifying `$s0` instead of using more temporaries, if you consider register allocation pressure as part of a large function.

But since there is no surrounding code, there's no reason to say there's anything wrong with yours.  Maybe it's useful to have the original `x` value around longer.

---

**Rearranging for a shorter critical path latency, and [instruction-level parallelism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction-level_parallelism) on a superscalar CPU**.  (e.g. [MIPS r10k](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R10000) is 4-wide superscalar with out-of-order execution)

There are three add / sub operations required, and both versions in your question have a serial dependency going through all three ALU operations.

2's complement arithmetic is associative.  But MIPS `add` faults on signed overflow, so it does matter what temporary results you create (just like for FP with rounding errors).  But MIPS also has `addu` which wraps instead of faulting, so if you don't care about raising an exception on signed overflow, use `addu` / `addiu` / `subu` and then you can reorder the operations to `(x - A[20]) + (y - 10)`, for example.

```
lw    $t0,   80($s3)       # load as early as possible
addiu $t1,   $s1,  -10     # y-10 in the shadow of the load delay slot
subu  $s0,   $s0,  $t0     # x-A[20]
addu  $s0,   $s0,  $t1
```

Notice that `x` (`$s0`) doesn't have to be ready until the 3rd instruction, so we can hide some latency for the `x` input.  If you know what instructions your operands are coming from, order your operations so the one likely to be ready last is needed last.  (Especially if you're tuning for an in-order CPU, unlike r10k)

Of course, if you expect some load latency, doing all the ALU work you can before using the load result makes more sense, even though this means serializing all three add/sub operations by making them dependent on each other.

Answer (score 4):

> When to use temporary and saved registers in MIPS Assembly language?

addendum to Peter Cordes answer.

The common calling convention(s) of MIPS assembly require you to preserve values in "saved" registers, and make you free to modify "temporary" registers, which comes into effect when you are calling subroutines from your code.

As the temporary registers are free to be modified by the subroutine, you have to preserve/restore them around the subroutine call, if you need the value, so temporary registers are often used between subroutine calls for values which can have limited lifetime.

The "saved" registers must be instead preserved by your code to not modify them for the caller above, i.e. whenever you are using another new saved register, you should put its original value somewhere (usually into stack memory) and then restore it before returning to the caller. This takes minor performance hit, so you may want to avoid "saved" registers completely in your code, unless you are calling several subroutines and you will instead gain performance by having values with longer life-cycle in the saved registers, not having to preserve/restore them around each call (if they are in temporary register).

So by a rule of thumb:

1. don't use register/value at all (eliminate by more clever algorithm or code structure, reusing already affected registers better)
2. use temporary for values with limited lifecycle, especially if it doesn't clash with subroutine calls
3. use saved register for values which have to stay around during subroutine calls (especially several subroutine calls)

(this is "calling CONVENTION" defined, i.e. you can define + use your own convention breaking the rules of temporary/saved register usage .. this is not something designed inside CPU)